# Get an error while using factorial function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, factorial, symbolic-math

When trying to compute this sequence I get an error

```
syms n
limit(((-3)^n)/factorial(n),inf)
```

Error using factorial (line 17)
N must be a matrix of non-negative integers.
Error in (line 9)

How do you fix this or specify the matrix they want?

Comment: You are creating a symbolic variable `n` via `syms` and then you are passing it to `factorial` function. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I know why its not working I am just asking how to fix it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The factorial function wasn't designed for use of symbolic references, and often chokes on them. It might work if you have a new enough version (2012b claims it works), but I don't think it'll necessarily work with older versions, I've found some documents claiming it won't in fact. The following two methods [have been suggested](http://users.aims.ac.za/~yibeltal/Academic/A%20Guide%20to%20MATLAB%20-%20For%20Beginners%20and%20Experienced%20Users,%20Second%20Edition.pdf) to work around the problem.

```
limit((-3)^n/sym('n!'),n,inf)
limit((-3)^n/gamma(n+1),n,inf)
```

Comment: I did some research, and came up with a few more possible solutions. I think they should work. Good Luck!